# Terminal does not change directory

Tags: terminal

I am not being able to change directory in terminal and I don't understand why.

This is what I get:

```
Annes-MBP:~ anne$ /Applications 
-bash: /Applications: is a directory
Annes-MBP:~ anne$ cd/Applications 
-bash: cd/Applications: No such file or directory
Anness-MBP:~ anne$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is the command, `/Applications` its parameter, and you need so separate commands and parameters by a space character. So in your case it's

```
cd /Applications
```

or, if you want to go back to your user's home folder

```
cd ~
```

or simply

```
cd
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I had canceled the space myself thinking it was a typo.